# JavaScript: Arrays. Why does concatenating an empty array with a populated array result in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I was working on a problem for flattening arrays. I came across something really strange and can't seem to find an answer online about it.

Why does

```
[] + [1,2] = '1,2'
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around why adding an empty array to a populated one results in a string with the contents of the populated array.

What is happening behind the scenes that causes this?

Example from my code:

```
arr = [1, [2], [3, 4]];
arr.reduce(flatten, []); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

function flatten(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}
```

As far as I understand, reduce will set '[]' as the 'initial value' and thus for each element in the original array it will concatenate it with an empty array thus "flattening" the array.

Comment: JavaScript is not Python, the + operator does not concatenate lists. The arrays are being coerced to a string. Try `[1,2].toString();`.

Comment: `+` is both the arithmetic addition and _string_ concatenation operator. So the arrays are converted to strings automatically to match the argument type of the operator. Check out [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=control) for array concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of **JavaScript's [implicit type coersion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#converting-values)** triggered by the `+` operator. You can't simply perform a `+` operation on arrays, so they are converted to strings (which contain the comma-separated string-converted values of the array).

Answer (score 5):

When you use `+` between objects (arrays are objects), JavaScript calls `toString()` and/or `valueOf()` internally.

```js
var coercion1 = {} + {foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'},
    coercion2 = [] + ['foo', 'bar'];

console.log(coercion1);
console.log(coercion2);
```

This is the same thing as:

```js
var coercion1 = "".concat({}.toString(), {foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'}.toString()),
    coercion2 = "".concat([].toString(), ['foo', 'bar'].toString());

console.log(coercion1);
console.log(coercion2);
```

Which is, again, the same thing as:

```js
var coercion1 = "".concat({}.valueOf(), {foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'}.valueOf()),
    coercion2 = "".concat([].valueOf(), ['foo', 'bar'].valueOf());

console.log(coercion1);
console.log(coercion2);
```

---

> To convert an object to a string, JavaScript takes these steps:
>
> - If the object has a **toString()** method, JavaScript calls it. If it returns a primitive value, JavaScript converts that value to a
>     string (if it is not already a string) and returns the result of that
>     conversion. [...]
> - If the object has no **toString()** method, or if that method does not return a primitive value, then JavaScript looks for a
>     **valueOf()** method. If the method exists, JavaScript calls it. If the return value is a primitive, JavaScript converts that value to a
>     string (if it is not already) and returns the converted value.
> - Otherwise, JavaScript cannot obtain a primitive value from either **toString()** or **valueOf()**, so it throws a TypeError.

**David Flanagan**, *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide*

Answer (score -1):

Using + will result in a string and the console exclude the brackets. Same as

```
''+[1,2]
```

Comment: It is not the console that excludes the brackets.

Comment: Maybe not expressed correctly but that is what happens. If you do {uno:11, dos:22} + "" brackets are added. Visually speaking

Comment: Um, nope. That gives the default `[object Object]`. We're talking about arrays, not POJOs, and they stringify to comma delimited values. If you want brackets, use `JSON.stringify` instead of string coercion.

Comment: Do a .length on your [object Object], the brackets are counted despite of being just the visual representation of the object converted to a string

Comment: Again, arrays have a custom `toString` implementation, they do not yield the same strings as objects. In fact, one can use this to test for whether an object *is* an array: `Object.prototype.toString.call([1,2]) === '[object Array]'` but `[1,2].toString() === '1,2'`.